# Loading a php snippet on a modal with an ajax call and posting from the form causing to call it multiple times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In a form I have a modal skeleton--meaning the modal body is empty. I designed number of on the fly add(for dropdowns) form and loading with a ajax post call like

```
    var scriptname,initiator;
    $(".launch-add-form").click(function(e){
         scriptname=($(this).prop('id')).split("-")[0] ;
         initiator=$(this).prop('id');
         $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"<?=site_url()?>/admin/commoncontroller/getform/",
            data:{csrftoken:cct,scriptname:scriptname}          
         }).done(function(res){ $("#modalBody").html(res) ;})       

    });
```

Which returns any script that matches the script name and render the response to the modal body. Well now from modal i fill the form and save it which properly works but the problem is on the main form there are multiple drop-downs and each have

```
      .launch-add-form class
```

Well, if I save with one drop down and try to do with other, then the ajax save call is being called like in geometric progression...1st 1 call than 2 calls then 4 calls...

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are assigning the onClick event multiple times.

try unbinding any clic event before adding a new one:

```
$(".launch-add-form").unbind( "click" );
```

so your code will be:

```
    var scriptname,initiator;

    $(".launch-add-form").unbind( "click" );

    $(".launch-add-form").click(function(e){
         scriptname=($(this).prop('id')).split("-")[0] ;
         initiator=$(this).prop('id');
         $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"<?=site_url()?>/admin/commoncontroller/getform/",
            data:{csrftoken:cct,scriptname:scriptname}          
         }).done(function(res){ $("#modalBody").html(res) ;})       

    });
```

Comment: You r right..Sorry that I didnt mention I solved it almost then..yeah it was right on your way..so I did..though a little differently. I added .off() method instead to the save method right after the line preventDefault().. It works nice.. Thank u anyway. I will tick your answer.